# What else can be done about incorrectly flagged posts?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, flagging

I regularly see questions related to chess programming flagged as off-topic. As voted on in [this meta question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/9025), they are on-topic. I vote to leave them open and continue, but is there anything else I can do?

I suspect it's the same user flagging them, but I obviously can't be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can leave a comment (which I [just did](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18229/what-is-the-problem-with-my-negamax-implementation#comment25554_18229) – I went to Meta to search for the poll, and found your question already waiting).

> The [community has decided](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/7297) that questions about chess programming are **on-topic**. This is also stated in the [help center](/help/on-topic): *Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.*

<sub>(see below for the source Markdown)</sub>

Hopefully, that will remind the close voter that *the Community* has decided that this is in scope, it's not a one-sided decision by the ♦ moderators or Stack Overflow the company.

We'll probably get programming questions which would be considered too broad on Stack Overflow; I think that's fine, our standards don't need to be so high; because of the low volume we can handle bad questions with ease. However, I do think it's important to stress the authors to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Chess Stack Exchange should not become a debugging service for chess engines.

In those cases, using the standard 'not in scope' reason isn't really constructive. The author of the question will visit the help page, but will see nothing that explicitly says their question is off-topic. I'd recommend using a custom off-topic reason then.

---

Source Markdown for the comment:

```
The [community has decided](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/q/418/7297) that questions about chess programming are **on-topic**. This is also stated in the [help center](/help/on-topic): *Chess-specific questions about programming a chess engine or other chess software are welcome.*
```

Comment: I  have left a general comment a couple of time, when I've read the question before checking out the review queues, which is why I suspect it's one person.